# Disable Button OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have an `asp.net` application which is a random generator and I want my button to disable and stay disabled when clicked.

I have tried adding `OnClientClick="this.disabled = true;"` to my `<asp:button>` and also tried adding the following to my onclick in the code behind
`BtnDecideForMe.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;");` but none of these work.

Not bothered how its done as long as it's clean and does the job.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <asp:Button class="btn btn-success" ID="BtnDecideForMe" runat="server" Text="Decide For Me" OnClick="BtnDecideForMe_Click" />
</div>
```

**On_Click Event**

```
protected void BtnDecideForMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> Eat = new List<string>();
    Eat.Add("Chinese Buffet");
    Eat.Add("Harvester");
    Eat.Add("Frankie & Benny's");
    Eat.Add("Hungry Horse");
    Eat.Add("Blaize");
    Eat.Add("Chiquito");
    Eat.Add("Cafe Football");
    Eat.Add("Nando's");

    Random Place = new Random();
    int Places = Place.Next(0, Eat.Count);
    txtDestination.Text = Eat[Places];
  //BtnDecideForMe.Enabled = false;
}
```

I don't really want to use `BtnDecideForMe.Enabled = false;` as it loses my `bootstrap` styling and don't really want to apply a whole lot of `css`.

Comment: When you say stay disabled do you mean even after postback a page reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not want I wanted to do but I decide to duplicate code (not the best I no but it does the job), anyway answer below:

```
<% if (txtDestination.Text == "")
{%>
    <asp:Button class="btn btn-success" ID="BtnDecideForMe" runat="server" Text="Decide For Me" OnClick="BtnDecideForMe_Click" />
<%}
else
{ %>
    <button class="btn btn-success" disabled>Decided</button>
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code in button click event.

```
BtnDecideForMe.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: @vidhyardhiI I do have your suggestion in my code already but I have commented it out as the enabled style doesn't look like my `bootstrap` style I am using an I would have to create a whole lot of `.css` so decided not to go with this.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you can achieve that using below code snippet. This will disable the button when the form is posted and remove the disabled attribute once completed.

```
  $(document).on('invalid-form.validate', 'form', function () {
        var button = $(this).find('input[type="submit"]');
        setTimeout(function () {

            button.removeAttr('disabled');
        }, 1);
    });
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {
        var button = $(this).find('input[type="submit"]');
        setTimeout(function () {

            button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }, 0);
    });
```

Comment: I have tried adding your code but it doesn't disable when clicked. I have added my whole on-click to my post in case this helps

Comment: Have you received any errors? Anything that might be useful. This should work if you have the jquery reference and the right button id

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into asp.net much, but if you're just trying to use jQuery to disable a button on click can you target it as you would any other element and use something like this?

```
  $(document).on("click", "#your-buttons-id", function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  });
```

http://codepen.io/jonathanrbowman/pen/jbZVyL#0

Comment: I have tried adding your code but it doesn't disable when clicked. I have added my whole on-click to my post in case this helps